# How to use limitation specific field value during display

Tags: mysql, cakephp

How can I will use substr in detail field?

This is my code:

```
<td><?php echo $newses['details']; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$newses['details']` is type of string just use:

```
<?php echo substr($newses['details'], 0, 10); ?>
```

But if you want to do it in CakePHP way, use [`truncate()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html#TextHelper::truncate) method of [TextHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html).

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
echo $this->Text->truncate(
  $newses['details'],
  10
);
```